# How can I insert a data using react-phone-number-input?, validation error when I'm inserting a phone number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I'm trying to insert a data with out say "phone number required". I filled the phone number field and it's full but when I'm clicking in submit, phone number field validation says "phone number required", despite I inserted the phone number in phone number field.

This is the validation of phone number:

```
     if(!values.phoneNumber){
              errors.phoneNumber = 'phoneNumber required'
               }
```

And this is my widget Number Phone:

import React,{useState} from 'react';

import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css';
import PhoneInput,{isValidPhoneNumber } from 'react-phone-number-input';

```
             const PhoneWidget = ({

                  step,
                  precision,
                  input,
                  placeholder,
                  label,
                  theme,
                  props,
                  meta: { valid,touched, error },
                  ...rest
                  }) =>
                  {

             const [value,setValue] = useState();


                    return(
                        <div className='form-group'> 
                        <label forname={input.name}>{label}</label> <br />
                         <PhoneInput
                           value={value}
                          placeholder={!input.value ? 'Please, type a number' : input.value}
                             //ISSUE  onChange={event => OnValueChange(event)}
                                    //Problem is here. Maybe I'm not setting the value
                                    onChange= {setValue}
                                              error={value ? (isValidPhoneNumber(value) ? undefined : 
                            'Invalid phone number')    : 'Number Phone required'}
                                     className='form-control'
                                           />
                                  //Here I get the validation error.
                                 {(!valid && touched) &&
                                     <p className='help-block'>{error}</p>
                                           }
                                {/*  <div className='text-danger' style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
                                         {touched && error}
                                          </div>*/      
                                       </div>

                                           )
                                        }


                export default PhoneWidget;
```

I can't understand. I type a data in number phone field and when I'm clicking on submit while number phone field is full, The number phone field gets and show validation error says "number phone required".

Any one knows I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write  `onChange= {setValue}` as onChange={e=>setValue(e.target.value)}

Comment: I've got this issue: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined